# How to compare rows within a dataframe column and check if value is changing?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as seen:

[image]

How to check conditions when results change from 'NO' to 'OK' and if it does populate the next column as true. Results should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['check'] = df['Result'].eq('OK') & df['Result'].shift().eq('NO')
print(df)

# Output:
  Result  check
0     NO  False
1     OK   True
2     OK  False
3     NO  False
4     OK   True
5     OK  False
6     OK  False
7     NO  False
```

To display correctly:

```
df['check'] = df['check'].replace({True: 'TRUE', False: ''})
print(df)

# Output:
  Result check
0     NO      
1     OK  TRUE
2     OK      
3     NO      
4     OK  TRUE
5     OK      
6     OK      
7     NO
```